# Empty table rows becomes transparent right before page curl transition

Tags: ios, uitableview, page-curl

I have a table view. When you add a new item to the table, I display a form sheet for you to enter the name and description of the item to be added to the table. When you press Done, the modal view dismisses and the item's detail view is pushed. Instead of pushing the detail view like you normally would with a navigation controller, I use a page curl transition.

```
    DetailViewcontroller *detailViewcontroller = [[DetailViewcontroller alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        detailViewcontroller.coolObject = collectionOne;

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration: 1.00];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:.25];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.navigationController.view cache:YES];

        //Start Animation
        [UIView commitAnimations];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewcontroller animated:NO];

        [detailViewcontroller release];
```

This works perfectly when there's enough populated rows to fill the screen. However, if there's only a few rows populated, the rest of the table becomes transparent where there's no rows right before the page curl transition and you can see parts of the detail view underneath right before the page curl transition loads.

It looks like the detail view is displayed first, then an empty shell of a view curls away after the fact.

I have set the table rows and table background color to black, white, anything but clearColor, and it still does it.

Is it a timing issue? Should I put timing in to make sure that the detail view isn't pushed until after the modal view is dismissed? Maybe tell the Add item controller to display the detail view and not the tableview's addViewDisDimiss delegate method?

Comment: I think it might be bcoz of, your first view controller.view's background color is clearColor. Try to set it as white/ any color

Comment: As I stated, I have set that to black and white and it still does it when there are empty rows.